# Connecting to MS SQL Server 2005 using PHP 8.0 or PHP 7.4

Tags: php, pdo, sql-server-2005

I am rebuilding a service that is using MSSQL Server 2005 along with PHP 4.3.11. There is a maintenance issue that I will need to address, and I would prefer to not write obsolete code now only to have to rewrite it later. I have been looking into the PDO_SQLSRV driver. It appears that Microsoft does not test new driver versions on software that has reached it's EOS. Has anyone attempted to use the 5.8 or 5.9 PHP Drivers for SQL Server on MSSQL Server 2005?

Comment: No I haven't. But one idea might be to put the database on a newer SQL server version but run the database itself in compatibility mode to minimise the risk of change.

Comment: Hmmmm... that is a good idea... I'll look into doing that...